# Javascript - Call a function when i send a from trought an href

Tags: javascript

// some input parameters
        Add

When i click on "Add" i need to call the loadingArtP() function before send the form, but it doesnt work. How can do it?

Comment: Why not use an `<input type="submit"/>`?

Comment: to be honest, because i hate that "submit" bottom. Yeah, maybe i can change it with CSS, but i thought it was possible do it with an easy href stat :) any idea how change this button with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form programmatically skips the onsubmit listener (note that it's onsubmit, not onSubmit as in your code). You can either use a real submit button as KennyTM's comment suggested, or call the event listener manually before submitting via code.

Answer (score 1):

As KennyTM stated, you should use an

```
<input type="submit">
```

instead. This will ensure that the `submit` event is fired properly.